# Create dynamic pages from Json, in Dojo

Tags: javascript, html, json, mobile, dojo

I have a json file

```
{
    Introduction: 
    [
        {
            title:   "Introduction",
            toolbar: "Page 1",
            content: "cont, aabitant morbi tristique..."
        },
        {
            title:   "about",
            toolbar: "Page 2",
            content: "contesent vel nisi ipsum..."
        },
        {
            title:   "services",
            toolbar: "Page 3",
            content: "Cras adipiscing sapien nec..."
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to create dynamic pages in Dojo mobile. From the above Json three pages will be created with moving back and forward. I am getting problems. I am reading Json as:

```
  dojo.xhrPost({
        url: "start.json",
        handleAs: "json",
            var viewContainer = new dojox.mobile.ScrollableView({id:"viewContainer"});
        load: function(response) {
            for (key in response){
                        // creating each view heading and content here.........
                        //can you give some hint what should be here?
                    }
        }
```

How can I read above json and create dynamic views. What could be replace with this line in code `//can you give some hint what should be here?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you're reading json in the wrong way. 
dojo.xhrPost will send data to the url you specify in the url parameter : not retrieve the file in the url parameter. If you do it the way you're doing, you'll end up with an error such as "Unable to load start.json status:500"

So, in your case, to read the file, you should do a dojo.xhrGet instead.

Next, your viewContainer variable should not be placed like that, in the middle of the arguments (you are writing code mixed in the middle of object properties (!!!)).

So... you should be able to accomplish what you want by doing something like this :

```
require(["dojo/dom-construct", 
    "dojo/_base/xhr", 
    "dojox/mobile/parser", 
    "dojox/mobile", 
    "dojox/mobile/ScrollableView", 
    "dojox/mobile/Heading"],
            function(domConstruct) {

                dojo.xhrGet({
                    url : 'start.json',
                    handleAs : "json",
                    load : function(response) {

                        dojo.forEach(response.Introduction, function(page){
                            var node = domConstruct.create("div", {id : page.title}, "viewsContainer", "last");
                            var view = new dojox.mobile.ScrollableView({
                                id : page.title
                            }, node);
                            view.addChild(new dojox.mobile.Heading({label : page.title}));
                            view.startup();
                        });
                    },
                    error : function(err) {
                        console.debug("Error : ", err);
                    }
                });
            }
        );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 load: function(response) {
        for (key in response.Introduction){
                    // creating each view heading and content here.........
                }

 and try to debug data for key it should be any object that you pass 3 obj in json...
```

Comment: thanks. I updated question. //can you give some hint what should be here?

Answer (score 1):

```
here each key has three property that you define in json,now u can inject values to html view
by accessing property like this key.title,key.toolbar....,ex:- $('<p>' + key.title + '</p>');
```

Comment: I am using dojo mobile, so injecting values to html will not be fruitful. I need to make things like new p() etc and then append it.

Comment: See this part of my question: //can you give some hint what should be here?